# BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE table not found when running Test on Spring Batch 5

Tags: spring, spring-batch

On Spring Batch 4, the same Test runs fine, while on version 5 I get the title's error message.

Why in v4 it loads the batch tables without issue. What has changed in v5?
I couldn't find anything in the official migration guides.

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyConfig.class })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class MyIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;


    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
        ...
    }
```

I don't mention all test1 code, as runner never reaches it.

Error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:93)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1539)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:744)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:815)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.getJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:299)


...

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE in statement [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:327)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$SimplePreparedStatementCreator.createPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1643)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have `@EnableBatchProcessing` on one of your configuration classes, which is not required anymore with Spring Boot 3, see the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-batch-changes).

Comment: It works when I remove @EnableBatchProcessing, but I found also another way:

Added something like this in Config class:
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
      .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-hsqldb.sql")
      .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql")
      .build();
}

Comment: Removing `EnableBatchProcessing` fixed it for me.